# using std::tuple to construct a vector-based dataset refer to variadic-templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want make a class template like below:

```
template < typename... Args > class VectorTuple;
```

by example,

```
VectorTuple < long, double, string >
```

will instanced as

```
Tuple < vector < long >, vector < double > , vector < string > >
```

I am not familiar to variadic-templates. The worst method is to copy code from < tuple > and modify it. Is there an easy way to just directly use std::tuple to define my VectorTuple.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for `typedef` the `variadic-templates` type then,

```
template<typename... Args>
using VectorTuple = std::tuple<std::vector<Args>...>;
```

Now you can use it like

```
VectorTuple<long, double, std::string> obj;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use parameter pack expansion to transform the variadic template parameter pack `T...` into `std::vector<T1>`, ..., `std::vector<Tn>`. Then, define a template alias with `template<...> using`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Ts> using VT = std::tuple< std::vector<Ts>... >;    

void foo()
{
    VT<int, float, double> x;
    std::tuple< std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>, std::vector<double>> y = x;
}
```

Comment: Ah, parameter pack expansion, about the only pleasingly expressive feature in all of C++. Heh.